# Consider such a homogeneous linear recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$a_n$=3$a_{n-1}$+18$a_{n-2}$ with initial conditions $a_0$=1 and $a_1$=9.

a). Use the algorithm to find a solution.
b). Use induction to show that the solution that you found in a) is correct, be sure to check both base cases.

I figured out part a, but don't know a clue about part b

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have notes about this? Does solving the equation $x^2-3x-18=0$ ring a bell?

Comment: Since I don’t know what algorithms you’ve been taught, I can only guess; do you know one that uses the characteristic polynomial or equation? Your base cases are $n=0$ and $n=1$, checking that your closed form really does yield $1$ and $9$, respectively.

Answer (score 6):

A brief summary of part (a) (since you've already solved it). We make use of the characteristic equation
$$
r^2 - 3r - 18 = (r-6)(r+3) = 0
$$
from which we infer that $r_1 = 6$ and $r_2 = -3$. Thus, the solution to the linear recurrence will be of the form $a_n = C_16^n + C_2(-3)^n$. We now solve for the constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ using the initial conditions.
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l} a_0 = C_1\cdot 6^0 + C_2\cdot (-3)^0 = 1 \\ a_1 = C_1\cdot 6^1 + C_2\cdot (-3)^1 = 9\end{array}\right. \implies \left\{\begin{array}{l} C_1 + C_2 = 1 \\ 6C_1 -3C_2 = 9\end{array}\right. \implies \left\{\begin{array}{l} C_1 = \frac{4}{3} \\ C_2 = -\frac{1}{3}\end{array}\right.
$$
Thus we have our solution $a_n = \frac{4}{3}6^n -\frac{1}{3}(-3)^n = 8\cdot6^{n-1} + (-3)^{n-1}$.

Now, we must use induction to show that this formula is correct for all whole numbers $n$ where $n\geq 0$. We do this in two parts

1. Show that the formula is correct for $n=0$ and $n=1$; *(base cases)*
2. Show that if we assume the formula is correct for $n=k-2$ and $n=k-1$, it is also correct for $n=k$. *(induction step)*

If the proof technique is not entirely clear, it might help to read a bit about [strong induction](http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/BMC4/Handouts/induct/node6.html). Following the ladder analogy of induction (you use the previous rung to get to the next), in this question we use the *two* rungs below us to get to the next rung. Accordingly, our induction hypothesis must assume the formula is correct for both the rungs $n=k-2$ and $n=k-1$.

**Claim:** The sequence identified by the recurrence relation $a_n=3a_{n−1}+18a_{n−2}$ with initial conditions $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 9$ can be determined explicitly using the formula $a_n = 8\cdot6^{n-1} + (-3)^{n-1}$.

*Proof:* We verify the formula for $n=0$ and $n=1$:
$$
\begin{array}{l}a_0 = 8\cdot6^{0-1} + (-3)^{0-1} = \frac{8}{6} - \frac{1}{3} = 1\\ a_1 = 8\cdot6^{1-1} + (-3)^{1-1} = 8 +1 = 9\end{array} 
$$
Next, suppose that the formula holds for $n=k-2$ and $n=k-1$, then it follows that
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_{k} &=& 3a_{k-1}+18a_{k-2} \\&=& 3\left(8\cdot6^{k-2} + (-3)^{k-3}\right) + 18\left(8\cdot6^{k-3} + (-3)^{k-4}\right)\\&=& 4\cdot6\cdot6^{k-2} + 3\cdot(-3)^{k-3} + 4\cdot6^2\cdot6^{k-3} + 2\cdot3^2\cdot(-3)^{k-4}\\&=& 4\cdot6^{k-1} - (-3)^{k-2} + 4\cdot6^{k-1} + 2\cdot(-3)^{k-2}\\&=& 8\cdot6^{k-1} + (-3)^{k-2}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
which is just the formula for $n=k$. Thus, by the principle of mathematical induction, the claim holds. $\blacksquare$

Comment: why isn't the solution just use n, but use n-1?

Comment: You *assume* that the formula holds for $n-1$ and $n-2$, and show that that implies that $n$ holds. For example, if we know the equation holds for $n=5$ and $n=6$, then according to the proof above, it also holds for $n=7$. Or if we know $n=101$ and $n=102$ holds, then $n=103$ must hold too. 
Talking about $n=k-1$ and $n=k-2$ just generalizes this idea.